# Cannot pass Parameter value to datasource from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with select command as stored procedure. I want to pass a parameter value to the stored procedure from code behind during a buttonclick. However the value is not being passed. Any help will be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString=" 
<%$ ConnectionStrings:EMPYHT_ConnectionString %>"
SelectCommand="SPGETNAMES" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"> 
<SelectParameters>
<asp:Parameter Name="tnid" Type="String" DefaultValue="" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>


protected void but_mep_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      string tende=Session["TENDER"].ToString();
      SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["tnid"].DefaultValue = tende;
      grd_tendermedicineslist.DataBind();
      upnl_editquo.Update();
   }
```

Comment: It looks like you're pulling the value from Session.  Where are you putting that value into the Session?

Comment: The value is passing to the parameter .But not binding the grid.

Comment: I haven't worked with `SqlDataSource` in quite some time (years), but it looks like you're missing a step - namely actually executing the stored procedure perhaps?  [SqlDataSource.Select Method (DataSourceSelectArguments)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.select(v=vs.110).aspx)